# CPLEX OPL Error 5002: Constraint not convex

Tags: constraints, cplex, opl, mixed-integer-programming, convex

I'm trying to work with cplex opl and facing an error. I read the manual and googled but I still have no idea what I should do to fix this error due to my lacking of knowledge. Can anyone please help or give me ideas to figure this out? I really need your help.

I am programming a mixed-integer-programming model. I ran the configuration and get this error:

Error 5002: 'NachfrageAusZUgeordnetenDZs#0#0' is not convex

Here is the code of the constraint:

[constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRmDP.jpg)

Can someone tell my why I get this error? Why is the constraint not convex? And how can I change it to make it work?

Thanks in advance for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1):

Your constraint is not convex. You could try to get not convex part in your objective and then rely on

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/OptimalityTarget.html

Or you could also try some linearization methods. See:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=f48c280e-144b-46aa-abb9-906a4eb4219f&ps=25